# Split a string into parts

Tags: .net, vb.net, split, string-function

I am trying to split a string into parts but can't figure it out!

My main point is from a string

```
"hello bye see you"
```

read from `"bye" to "you"`

I tried

```
 Dim qnew() As String = tnew.Split(" ")
```

But I got stuck on other parts of the code, I would really like some help.
Sorry if I'm not the best at explaining things, at least I tried my best :/

Comment: "hello bye see you" read from "bye" to "you" .. didnt get that? can you please elaborate?

Comment: Please supply the rest of your code and try explaining your problem / requirement agian.

Comment: `String.Split()` doesnt work on a From-To basis.  Set a breakpoint and hold your mouse over `qnew` to see the result.  Still dont get it?  Oh well, *at least I tried my best*

Comment: Once you have the array with the split string, just take from index **1** to the last, skipping index **0** (which contains "hello").

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume that your expected output is  `bye see you`.If I understood correctly then following *methods* can be used to get the desired output:

In this string splits into an array(`splits()`) with delimiter `" "` and find index of `bye` (`j`)and `you`(`k`) in the array then using a `for loop` to get strings in the array between `bye` and `you`.

```
Function GETSTRINGBETWEEN(ByVal start As String, ByVal parent As String, ByVal [end] As String)
        Dim output As String = ""
        Dim splits() As String = parent.Split(" ")
        Dim i As Integer
        Dim j As Integer = Array.IndexOf(splits, start)
        Dim k As Integer = Array.IndexOf(splits, [end])
        For i = j To k
            If output = String.Empty Then
                output = splits(i)
            Else
                output = output & " " & splits(i)
            End If
        Next
        Return output
    End Function
```

Usage:

```
Dim val As String
val = GETSTRINGBETWEEN("bye", "hello bye see you", "you")
'val="bye see you"
```

---

```
Function GET_STRING_BETWEEN(ByVal start As String, ByVal parent As String, ByVal [end] As String)
        Dim output As String
        output = parent.Substring(parent.IndexOf(start) _
                                                , (parent.IndexOf([end]) _
                                                   - parent.IndexOf(start)) _
                                                   ).Replace(start, "").Replace([end], "")
        output = start & output & [end]
        Return output
    End Function
```

Usage:

```
Dim val As String
val = GET_STRING_BETWEEN("bye", "hello bye see you", "you")
'val="bye see you"
```

Comment: Thank you! Sorry for the late response, after I read this I figured it out :)